# How does when() work?

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

In the following example

```
when(myMethod("abc", 123)).thenReturn(456);
```

How does the `when()` method catch the method name and arguments without actually invoking `myMethod()`?

Can I write a method to do the same thing as `when()` so that I get a method pointer and an array of `Object`s as arguments to invoke later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `myMethod` *is* invoked.  But it is being invoked on a mock object -- that's the "trick".

Of course you can write code that accepts a "method pointer" (in Java, it would be an object of class `Method`) and some arguments, and use `invoke`, but doing so does not actually buy you anything over calling the mock object's `myMethod` directly.

It is more common to see `when` called as follows:

```
MyObject myObject = mock(MyObject.class);
when(myObject.myMethod("abc", 123)).thenReturn(456);
```

Try printing (or logging) the expression

```
myObject.getClass().getName()
```

here.  You will see that the class of the mock object is not actually `MyObject`.  But it is of a class that has the same interface.  The calls on this object update some internal state.  This allows Mockito to keep track of how it is used, and allows you to assert various things.

Comment: Yeah, I know how to invoke it manually. But I was hoping there was a cleaner way of doing it...

Comment: Ah I see. Which part does not look clean, though?  There may be other ways to set up a mocked scenario for stating the method returns 456 when passed "abc" and 123 -- what kind of syntax were you thinking about?

Answer (score 0):

In your above example, `myMethod` is a method on a mock object. Without any expectations, Mockito will return `null`, 0, or false depending on the data type, which `when` will silently discard.

However, You may also use `when` on an object which is not a mock, but rather an object created using `Mockito.spy()`. In this case, the method would actually be called in the `when` method, which is often not what you want to do. Mockito provides another method called `doReturn` (or possibly `doAnswer` or `doThrow`) which provides you a replacement object so the original is never called ([docs](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#do_family_methods_stubs)):

```
doReturn(1).when(mySpiedObject).getSomeInteger(anyString(), eq("seven"));
```

Note that the Mockito docs recommend using `when` rather than `doReturn` because the latter is [not type-safe](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#doReturn%28java.lang.Object%29).

Comment: Re your last paragraph.  What Mockito documentation says that?  I thought that bit had been taken out of the online docs.

Comment: @David It seems `when` is still preferred for reasons that were more-recently moved down to the `doReturn` method docs: There's no return value type checking on the `doReturn` calls.